# I have a crontab ,does not work

Tags: cron

I have a crontab like this. the python script will send a message to my phone.
when I execute '/usr/local/bin/python /home/work/alibaba-rocketmq/monitor/monitor.py ' on the command line,I can get the message. but in the crontab . It doesnot work.

why. Thanks for your help

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python /home/work/alibaba-rocketmq/monitor/monitor.py
```

Comment: You have one of several issues. Most common is the `cron` user's environment does not match your environment. This generally means that a python environment setting or path is not available to the `cron` user preventing the python script from running.. You can check your environment with `set | grep -i python` to see what is set and supplement the `cron` environment as needed. You are using absolute paths, so I suspect it is a python environment issue.

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use another approach and:

- Put your script in a file foo.py starting with

  ```
  #!/usr/local/bin/python
  ```
- Make sure you give execute permission to that script:

  ```
  chmod a+x /home/work/alibaba-rocketmq/monitor/monitor.py
  ```
- use only `/home/work/alibaba-rocketmq/monitor/monitor.py` in your crontab file.